# How to get rid of the arithmetic overflow

Tags: c++, arithmetic-overflow

This is the code for the Triangle problem in codility that is throwing me an arithmetic overflow error.

```
int solution(vector<int> &A) {

    int i, n;
    n=A.size();
    sort(A.begin(), A.end());
    for(i=0; i<n-2; i++)
    {
        if((A[i]+A[i+1]>A[i+2])&&(A[i]+A[i+2]>A[i+1])&&(A[i+1]+A[i+2]>A[i]))
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It passes all the tests except for the 'extreme_arith_overflow1 overflow test, 3 MAXINTs' saying the code returns 0 but it expects 1. Anybody have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: First of all make sure that you don't go out of bounds of your vector. (which you will do with the code you currently show) Secondly perhaps use `unsigned int` instead, (if no value can be negative) or maybe `long long` (or `unsigned long long`) for a 64-bit type? Also, you should probaby be doing some input validation to make sure the input you read is valid to begin with.

Comment: You store `A.size()` in `n` and then you loop until `i<n` and access `A[i+2]`. In the error cases this is `A[A.size()]` or even `A[A.size()+1]`. It's out of bounds.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yesss thanks i fixed the out of bounds issue and validated input :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You store `A.size()` in `n` and then you loop until `i<n` and access `A[i+2]`. In the error cases this is `A[A.size()]` or even `A[A.size()+1]`. It's out of bounds. Fix the range of the loop.

The next problem occurs when the sum is larger than `INT_MAX`. Use the difference instead of the sum to avoid overflow. Remember that the elements are sorted with `A[i] <= A[i+1] <= A[i+2]`

```
int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    if (A.size() < 3) return 0;
    const auto n = A.size() - 2;
    std::sort(A.begin(), A.end());
    for(decltype(n) i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if((A[i]>A[i+2]-A[i+1])&&(A[i+2]>A[i+1]-A[i])&&A[i]>0) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! Fixed the out of bounds issue but i still seem to be getting an arithmetic overflow error.

Comment: Now prone to underflow. :-) Consider `INT_MIN` -  1.

Comment: @jvd Where do you see underflow? `A` is sorted. `A[i+2]-A[i+1]` and `A[i+1]-A[i]` return positive values.

Comment: @ThomasSablik You are correct. I forgot that `A` was sorted.

Comment: The correct way to write the loop is 'for (size_t i = 0; i < A.size()-2; ++i)'

Comment: @UriRaz `int i = 0; i < A.size()-2` is an implicit check that `A.size()` is at least 3 before the loop. Of course you can add redundant checks.

Comment: @Thomas Sablik I tried to compile that on Visual Studio, and I get a warning - "warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch". Also, vector's size() returns size_t. If sizeof(int) <= sizeof(size_t), this might cause an infinite loop.

Comment: @UriRaz Fixed it.

Comment: If numbers can be negative, you still have overflows for the data `{ -2, -1, INT_MAX }`.

Comment: @j6t What would be a triangle with negative side length? Of course, you are right but this code solves the problem.